# Diagonal split to show two positions of the same video frame. Landscape input, portrait output

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 16:9 video with two faces talking to eachother. I want to make a portrait video output (for smartphones viewport) where I show both faces in the same frame, split diagonally. Is this possible? Like this: from [o o] to [%]

I have used a filter .script-file earlier to fit one face into the frame, but now I'd like to fit both faces from the same scene, and preferably diagonally.

The viewer will be able to see the two faces having a dialogue in a portrait aspect ratio, no matter how far away they are from eachother in the original landscape aspect ratio.

Comment: See [FFMPEG Crop with side by side merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352120/). Does that do what you want?

Comment: @llogan Exactly what I needed, thanks so much.